# Find out all classes in C# which implement Close() Method?

Tags: c#

I was trying to find all classes in `C#` which implement `Close()`. For example `Socket`, `StreamReader`, `StreamWriter` class in `C#` contains `Close()` method for closing resources.  Moreover, I noticed that some class implements `IDisposable`. Do all classes which contain `Dispose()` also contain `Close()`.

Comment: Did you mean `Dispose` instead of `Destroy`? If so, the answer is certainly "no". Many things implement `IDisposable` without having a `Close` method. Finding "all classes" requires specifying which assemblies you're interested in - once you've got those, if you can load them all with reflection, that's pretty simple.

Comment: Why are you trying to do that? What have you tried? Do you use reflection or do you just want to obtain a list from the Internet?

Comment: You can use in the menu : Edit : Find Symbols : All Components.  Then search for Close.  Some versions of VS eliminated the command from the menu bar.  So you can add a custom button to the toolbar and add the command from the edit command menu using customize option.  Right click a toolbar then select : Customize : Commands : Edit : Find Symbol.

Comment: @ThomasWeller I am working on a rule which states that all initialized resources  on try block must be closed on finally. So I need the list of all the classes in C# that implements close method.

Comment: @JonSkeet I need the list of all the classes in C# that implements IDisposable. r I am working on a rule which states that all initialized resources on try block must be closed on finally.

Comment: @PiyushAgarwal: There's no such thing as "classes in C#" - C# is a language, not a library. (It requires a few specific classes, but nothing like the full library.) But if you're trying to build a rule, you should be able to tell *in the rule* whether the class involved implements IDisposable. You definitely shouldn't have a *list*.

Comment: If you apply that rule to your coding guidelines, such an object may not live longer than one method. That's not possible in real life. Such objects must be closed **somewhere** but not necessarily in the *finally* block.

Answer (score 1):

That rule violation is trying to tell you that a class you initialized in the try implements IDisposable, and you don't have any code that calls the Dispose to reclaim its unmanaged resources. Classes that implement IDisposable are effectively "notifying you" that they need to be explicitly cleaned up. It's a very common pattern in .Net.

You could do something like:

```
SomeClassThatImplementsIDisposable x = null;
try
{
  x = new SomeClassThatImplementsIDisposable();
  //--> call methods on x... 
}
finally
{
  x.Dispose();
}
```

...but, what's far more common is to use a `using` block:

```
using ( var x = new SomeClassThatImplementsIDisposable() )
{
  //--> call methods on x...
}
```

...which causes the compiler to build a `try/finally` block out of your using block.

So...it's not a `Close` method you should be concerned about. When you get the rule violation, you should do one of the two things above (preferably the latter by convention).

Further, you don't really need to care about *all classes that have some method*. You just need to run your static analysis, and it will tell you when you've not cleaned things up. You'll ultimately become very familiar with this pattern.